# ActiveAdmin and in-place edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, edit-in-place

I have this system where I use ActiveAdmin to automate the backend and I was wondering if anyone tried to use in-place editing with tables for ActiveAdmin.

I see some scenarios where that would be useful: key-value tables (like State, Category, etc.) and in master-detail views (Order and OrderItems)...

Have anyone attempted to implement it? Any good pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've used best_in_place Editor but only on customized views, not on generic ones.

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place

```
gem "best_in_place"
bundle
rails g best_in_place:setup
```

Add the best_in_place script to `/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`:

```
//= require best_in_place

$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */  
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place() });
```

in your custom view partial you can have something like

```
.panel
  %h3 Your Resource Table
  .panel_contents
    .attributes_table
      %table
        %tbody
          %tr
            %th Name
            %td= best_in_place resource, :name, :type => :input, :path => [:admin, resource]
            ...
            ...
```

As ActiveAdmin has already setup your RESTful Actions and BestInPlace is using RESTful PUT to Update too, everything should work automatically :)

You may can also use something like this, but I've not tested this yet.

```
index do
  column(:name) { |i| best_in_place i, :name, :type => :input, :path => [:admin, i] } 
end
```

Comment: I have managed to use that very same plugin in the generic ones, with minor changes. Might as well do a blog post when I stop being lazy about it :) Thank you!

Comment: This is awesome. @kolrie I'm interested in seeing how you got it to work with the generic ones, did you have to monkey-patch ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 5):

Actually Best In Place monkey patch for Active Admin views is very easy:

```
# app/admin/active_admin/views.rb
module ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers
  extend BestInPlace::BestInPlaceHelpers
end
```

Comment: still works as of 3.1.0, but you want `BestInPlace::Helper`