# ActiveAdmin edit resource at index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have one resource(**Song**) in ActiveAdmin.

Now it has default index page.

How can i edit fields in this page.

I have a lot of resources(~10 000), so I need to update image(Paperclip) and one another field(**Album**  *has_many* **AlbumItems**, **AlbumItem** *belongs_to* **Song**, so I need to fill **Album** field for **Song**) at this page.

Comment: There is an ActiveAdmin [pull request #1815 pending](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1815) that allows batch action forms. You might also consider edit in place plugins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689747/activeadmin-and-in-place-edit. What is it you're attempting to accomplish? Updating shared fields across all songs in an album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this.
I have created new view, where added all features I need.
By I lost possibility of multiple actions, because I've got forms in form there.